# Alfresco workflow path does not exist

Tags: alfresco, workflow-activity

Hi guys for many times... Alfresco Community kills me, all the time. This time i have deployed a sample bpmn process with a single service task. I start the process from workflow console. And it throws me exception

```
org.alfresco.service.cmr.workflow.WorkflowException: 05300002 Workflow path activiti$209 does not exist.
at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiWorkflowEngine.getTasksForWorkflowPath(ActivitiWorkflowEngine.java:770)
at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowServiceImpl.getTasksForWorkflowPath(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:749)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.alfresco.service.cmr.workflow.WorkflowPermissionInterceptor.invoke(WorkflowPermissionInterceptor.java:57)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:159)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.getTasksForWorkflowPath(Unknown Source)
at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowInterpreter.endStartTaskForPath(WorkflowInterpreter.java:1275)
at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowInterpreter.executeCommand(WorkflowInterpreter.java:870)
at org.alfresco.repo.admin.BaseInterpreter$1$1.execute(BaseInterpreter.java:155)
at org.alfresco.repo.admin.BaseInterpreter$1$1.execute(BaseInterpreter.java:1)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:326)
at org.alfresco.repo.admin.BaseInterpreter$1.doWork(BaseInterpreter.java:158)
at org.alfresco.repo.admin.BaseInterpreter$1.doWork(BaseInterpreter.java:1)
at org.alfresco.repo.security.authentication.AuthenticationUtil.runAs(AuthenticationUtil.java:548)
at org.alfresco.repo.admin.BaseInterpreter.interpretCommand(BaseInterpreter.java:147)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.admin.DynamicInterpreterExtension.interpretCommand(DynamicInterpreterExtension.java:104)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.admin.DynamicInterpreterExtension.executeCmd(DynamicInterpreterExtension.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_repository_admin_consoles_admin_workflowconsole_post_js_5._c_main_8(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/admin/consoles/admin-workflowconsole.post.js:191)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_repository_admin_consoles_admin_workflowconsole_post_js_5.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/admin/consoles/admin-workflowconsole.post.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName0(OptRuntime.java:74)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_repository_admin_consoles_admin_workflowconsole_post_js_5._c_script_0(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/admin/consoles/admin-workflowconsole.post.js:199)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_repository_admin_consoles_admin_workflowconsole_post_js_5.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/admin/consoles/admin-workflowconsole.post.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_repository_admin_consoles_admin_workflowconsole_post_js_5.call(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/admin/consoles/admin-workflowconsole.post.js)
at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.classpath__alfresco_templates_webscripts_org_alfresco_repository_admin_consoles_admin_workflowconsole_post_js_5.exec(classpath*:alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/repository/admin/consoles/admin-workflowconsole.post.js)
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.executeScriptImpl(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:502)
at org.alfresco.repo.jscript.RhinoScriptProcessor.execute(RhinoScriptProcessor.java:200)
at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.execute(ScriptServiceImpl.java:212)
at org.alfresco.repo.processor.ScriptServiceImpl.executeScript(ScriptServiceImpl.java:174)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryScriptProcessor.executeScript(RepositoryScriptProcessor.java:102)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractWebScript.executeScript(AbstractWebScript.java:1376)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.DeclarativeWebScript.execute(DeclarativeWebScript.java:86)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer$3.execute(RepositoryContainer.java:512)
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecute(RepositoryContainer.java:580)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.transactionedExecuteAs(RepositoryContainer.java:649)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScriptInternal(RepositoryContainer.java:421)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.RepositoryContainer.executeScript(RepositoryContainer.java:301)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:378)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.AbstractRuntime.executeScript(AbstractRuntime.java:209)
at org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.WebScriptServlet.service(WebScriptServlet.java:132)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.GlobalLocalizationFilter.doFilter(GlobalLocalizationFilter.java:61)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

my bpmn code file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
<process id="ProtocolUserRequestStepByStep" name="Protocol User Request Step By Step" isExecutable="true">
<startEvent id="startevent1" name="Start"></startEvent>
<serviceTask id="servicetask1" name="Copy request to the central protocol folder" activiti:class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.script.AlfrescoScriptDelegate">
  <extensionElements>
    <activiti:field name="script">
      <activiti:string><![CDATA[execution.setVariable('testVariable', 2);
                    logger.log("The variable is " + execution.getVariable('testVariable'));]]></activiti:string>
     </activiti:field>
   </extensionElements>
 </serviceTask>
 <sequenceFlow id="flow1" sourceRef="startevent1" targetRef="servicetask1"> </sequenceFlow>
 <endEvent id="endevent1" name="End"></endEvent>
 <sequenceFlow id="flow2" sourceRef="servicetask1" targetRef="endevent1">       </sequenceFlow>
 </process>
```

I can't understand the reason for these errors.
Thx for your time and support

Comment: don't anyone know something, about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know, why alfresco does that... 
 But it seems, that there is a bug to alfresco, which you have to include (in your workflow) a user task and pass from it. 
So, if you don't want to use a user task, you just have to end it by code. More info for how to close a user task [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38250242/solvedhow-to-end-alfrescos-human-task)

Thx for your time